# Initializing stl classes with template parameters

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, initialization, std

I am trying to do declare a stl map with template parameters like so:
( assume T as typename like so : `template <class T>`)

`map<T, T> m;` ( in .h file )

It compiles fine. now in my cpp file, when I want to insert into the map, i am not able to. The only methods i get on intellisense are "at" and "swap" methods.

Any ideas? Anyone please?

Thanks in advance.

here is sample code:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 

class MySample  
{  
map<T, T> myMap;
//other details omitted

public:

//constructor 
MySample(T t)
{
    //here I am not able to use any map methods. 
    //for example i want to insert some elements into the map
    //but the only methods I can see with Visual Studio intellisense
    //are the "at" and "swap" and two other operators
    //Why???
    myMap.  
}

//destructor
~MySample(void)
{

}
//other details omitted
};
```

Comment: Post some code... We're not in front of your screen, so you may want to help us understanding your problem, if you want answers...

Comment: I added some sample code. Let me know if what I am doing is wrong.

Comment: If you just type code along the lines described in my answer, does the code compile then? Perhaps this is simply a problem of the auto-suggest function of your IDE.

Comment: Parsing C++ and resolving all the names of identifiers correctly is *monstrously* complicated.  It's hard enough writing a compiler that gets this right, and IntelliSense has to produce something sensible much faster than a full compile, and even when the code is in a syntactically broken state.  It's amazing that it works as well as it does, but don't rely on it!  It's just a "best effort" heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

The usual ways to insert key-value pairs into a `std::map` are the index-operator syntax as well as the `insert` function. I'll assume `std::string` for keys and `int` for values for the sake of the example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string,int> m;
m["hello"] = 4;  // insert a pair ("hello",4)
m.insert(std::make_pair("hello",4)); // alternative way of doing the same
```

If you can use C++11, you may use the new uniform initialization syntax instead of the `make_pair` call:

```
m.insert({"hello",4});
```

And, as said in the comments, there is

```
m.emplace("hello",4);
```

in C++11, which constructs the new key-value pair in-place, rather than constructing it outside the map and copying it in.

---

I should add that since your question is actually about *initialization*, rather than inserting fresh elements, and given that indeed you do this in the constructor of `MyClass`, what you should really do (in C++11) is this:

```
MySample(T t)
 : myMap { { t,val(t) } }
{}
```

(Here I assume there is some function `val` which generates the value to store for `t` in the map.)

Comment: In C++11, you can also use [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace).

Comment: I added some sample code. Let me know if what I am doing is wrong.

Comment: @MarceloCantos So you can indeed! Thanks. (My GCC 4.7.0 implementation of the STL doesn't seem to define `std::map<>::emplace` though.)